# MediaController.show(0) error

Tags: android, android-videoview, mediacontroller

I'm inflating layout with VideoView into ViewPager.

Here is code in `instantiateItem` function:

```
RelativeLayout v = (RelativeLayout) li.inflate(R.layout.background34, null);

vv = (VideoView)v.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
            Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.advetime);
MediaController mc = new MediaController(context);
mc.setAnchorView(vv);
mc.setMediaPlayer(vv);
vv.setMediaController(mc);
mc.show(0);
vv.setVideoURI(video);
vv.start();
```

my app crashes at line `mc.show(0)` with error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(24284): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(24284): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
```

What is the problem? Help me please.

Comment: when `mc.show(0) ... vv.start()` is called view `v` is not connected to any Window ... you need to choose better place (not `instantiateItem`) to start video

Comment: I placed button in view that I'm inflating in `instantiate` func. `OnClickListener` of this button now do
`vv = (VideoView)v.findViewById(R.id.videoView);`
            `Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.advetime);`
`MediaController mc = new MediaController(context);`
`mc.setAnchorView(vv);`
`mc.setMediaPlayer(vv);`
`vv.setMediaController(mc);`
`mc.show(0);`
`vv.setVideoURI(video);`
`vv.start();`
I'm still recieving this error